# Making a program to be updated by users

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a prototype for the company that I'm interning for.  I would like to create a program that allows users to make minor updates that will, within 15ish seconds or so, update on everyone's screen.  This program will only be used by about 20 people at one time at the most.  For instance, if a person were to type click a button that went from red to green, the change to green would show on everyone's screen.  I only know Java, but I'm not opposed to learning other languages.  I'm just looking for places to read about this type of stuff, or ways that you know to do it.

I'm also hoping to allow an admin account to make usernames for people with differing amounts of access to making updates, but this is the later part to my project.

Thanks

Comment: With a central server? Or decentralized?

Comment: Should it be web or desktop based?

Comment: desktop based would be ideal, although it can be either.  It would be on a centralized server - hosted through the company.

Comment: It would be better if your company post a job offer so we can apply to make this application as well :)

Comment: It's actually not part of my job description.  I just see a way that part of the company can be more standardized and efficient, so I'm going to create a prototype and pitch it to my boss.

Comment: *It's actually not part of my job description* but is part of most experienced people here, so I suggest writing the job offer as quick as you can :).

Comment: Enough jokes. There are lot of possible solutions to come up with this problem. You must at least define your architecture and then start working on the project. Also, from your last comment: *there may be people interacting from the US and India on this* since you don't give enough info about the real problem, there's simply no way to even provide a real solution. Will the application should react always on 15 secs for any server? Will use a centralized database for failover issues? Do you have enough bandwidth to support geographical communication between server and clients? And on and on...

Comment: I agree with Luiggi.  There's not enough information to help you as much as we'd like.  Hopefully the suggestions I've given you will help.  Come back once you've more info on requirements, we'll be more able to assist then.

Comment: I'm aware that the information I gave was very vague.  I work for a very large data company, so it is hard for me to accurately define the architecture since I've only been interning here 3 weeks.  I'll be able to host this on the companies servers, and 95% of the people will be using the program on the same LAN. We have to convert clients files to our system which is kind of a mess.  It is 15 people sitting in a chatroom running seperate jobs.  I want to make a nice GUI that shows the jobs to everyone and when someone runs one they can click it and verify that they ran it to all others.

Comment: I'm studying comp sci and math at my university, I just don't have experience in this field - I'm just trying to learn what I need to start and I can go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only 20 users or so, your options are pretty much wide open.  You can use TCP or UDP, a web server with HTTP.  I'd use TCP myself.

It will be easy to update only 20 people with small updates within 15 seconds.

Here's how to create a [TCP server in C#.net](http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server)
Here's how to create a simple [TCP server in Java](http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/).

I suggest using [ProtoBufs](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) for the binary protocol. Its simple, compact, and allows you to change your language without needing to rewrite protocol parsing/unparsing code.

Comment: It should be noted that there may be people interacting from the US and India on this, will the distance cause complications in terms of web based vs desktop based?

Comment: Web based won't allow you to push updates from the server instantly, and so will require a bit more bandwidth as clients will need to poll to see status of other users.

The distance may make updates slower but still, 15 seconds is easily possible as long as data is small. That's all I see the distance affecting. Speed.

Comment: Thank you very much, William.  The toughest part for me is figuring out where to get started, so this helps immensly.

Comment: No problem.  Please accept this as the answer to close your question if you're satisfied.